# Torch CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package) in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, torch

I am trying to create a `Eclipse C++` project by `CMake` which calls `torch/torch.h` . I run `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ./` to create a `Eclipse` project, but I get this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Torch", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Torch" with any of
  the following names:

    TorchConfig.cmake
    torch-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Torch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Torch"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

In which `CMakeLists.txt` is located in the current directory that has:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)        
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)    
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Apparently, it cannot find `TorchConfig.cmake` and `torch-config.cmake` files; although, I **have** `TorchConfig.cmake` in `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch`. I added the corresponding path into the `CMakeLists.txt` file by testing each of:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
set(Torch_DIR "/home/afshin/libtorch;${Torch_DIR}")
set(Torch_DIR "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch;${Torch_DIR}")
set(Torch_DIR "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake;${Torch_DIR}")
set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
```

But, it did not help and I still get same error. 
I appreciate any help or comments.

I also tried the cmake-gui and I get same error:

[image]

Thanks,
Afshin

Comment: So where is this file located?

Comment: Can you run cmake-gui and check flat paths are being picked up?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It is under a new directory in my eclipse workspace:
ls eclipse-workspace/test_cmake/
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  CMakeLists.txt  src

Comment: The ,cmake file that CMake is looking for.

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu I get same error. It is worthy to mention that Torch_DIR was empty and I added it manually, though it did not help.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I did not find `FindTorch.cmake`, I mean locate cannot find it. Two other mentioned files are in `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch`.

Comment: Can you set Torch_DIR to `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/` or `/home/afshin/libtorch/share`? and try? If FindTorch doesn't exist, changing `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` doesn't change the result.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I tried both and still same error.

Comment: So to be clear, you cannot manually find FindTorch.cmake on your system. Can you fetch one from the internet and put it in one of the Cmake paths?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu Good idea, but no success. Although, I believe that it should be built in the compile time of the code.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/torch/torch7), torch should have `TorchConfig.cmake` file (it is based on `cmake/TorchConfig.cmake.in` from the source tree). If your torch installation lacks for this file, this is problem by itself. Without that file the command `find_package(Torch)` won't work. (But you may include directories and link libraries manually).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do have `TorchConfig.cmake` which is in `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/`. So, there is no problem with that. But, now the question is how can I let `cmake` know this directory?

Comment: Hmm, your question post tells the opposite: "Apparently, it cannot find `TorchConfig.cmake` and `torch-config.cmake` files.". Could you update the question post for reflect the actual situation? If you have that file, setting `Torch_DIR` in the cache should work. I don't know why it doesn't (according to the screenshot, you have tried this and failed). Note, that `Torch_DIR` is essentially **single-value** variable, setting it to the list won't work. You may also try to set variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/home/afshin/libtorch`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Well, it is what it is. The error says "Could not find a package configuration file provided by `Torch` with any of the following names: `TorchConfig.cmake`, 1torch-config.cmake1." So, that is also part of the problem. I know where are those files, but cmake does not. The question is how I can tell to cmake the location of those files. I used `Torch_DIR` and it gives same error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I also added `set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")`, or `set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")` or `set(DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share;${DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")`, but neither helped.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It worked now. I added `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` instead of `DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with value of `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch`. Now configure and generate are working fine.

Comment: I am glad that you resolve your problem but a path `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch` looks weird for variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`- this variable normally contains installation prefixes of the programs, not their inner directories. Now I re-read your question post, and find it to be correct... but could you make it more clear? I mean adding something like "I **have** the file `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake` and curious why CMake cannot find it, despite my settings."

Comment: @Tsyvarev I edited as you suggested.

Comment: "... it cannot find `TorchConfig.cmake` and `torch-config.cmake` files; although, I **have** them ..." - It is unlikely that you have **both** these files. Actually, exactly this wording confused me before.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Now, I see your point. You are right, I do not have both. Indeed the other file is `TorchConfigVersion.cmake`. I updated the question with this. Thanks for your point. Hopefully, now the question is precise enough to help other people in future.

Comment: Yes, the question becomes much clearer now. As for "Update" at the end - it looks like a solution, and on Stack Overflow we tend to not mix solution with a question in a single post. Instead, you may create [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and move that code into it. Make sure that you check the code: setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should come **before** `find_package()` call and do not contain comma (`,`) - in CMake comma isn't a separator symbol. You may check that your code works by removing `CMakeCache.txt` file from the build directory and re-run configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the suggestions. I posted an answer with a tested solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test_cmake)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_cmake ./src/test_cmake.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_cmake "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET test_cmake PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Alternatively, using the `cmake-gui` also I was able to solve the problem by the following setting:

[image]

by hitting `configure`, and then `generate`. 
Finally, I imported this project into `Eclipse` by selecting `Makefile Project With Existing Code`. This code is compiled and built successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The following modified `CMakeLists.txt` file works without the apparently missing `TorchConfig.cmake` (also missing in the `vcpkg` installation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/torch-th)). I recommend Microsoft's `vcpkg` for cross-platform packages (c++ libraries) management (usage [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.md)). But the code is vcpkg independent: one can set `TORCH_BASE_PATH` (or `Torch_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Torch_LIBRARIES`) to the proper paths.

```
#[[
    tested with:
    - CMake 3.13
    - Visual Studio Community Edition 15.9.4
        (CMake generator: "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64")
    - torch-th library installed with vcpkg
        generic: vcpkg install torch-th
        for macOS: vcpkg install torch-th:x64-osx-dynamic
            x64-osx-dynamic triplet must be created: x64-osx + "set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE dynamic)"
        for Windows: vcpkg install torch-th:x64-windows

    - easy torch sample: https://apaszke.github.io/torch-internals.html
    ]]
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

# cannot work without a "package configuration file" (TorchConfig.cmake)
#   so we replace it with find_path and find_library
#find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

#[[ 
    the environement variable VCPKG_ROOT used here, contains the path to vcpkg installation folder
        replace the two paths with your paths to TH installation

    usage: #include "TH/TH.h"
    ]]
set(TORCH_BASE_PATH "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}")
message(STATUS TORCH_BASE_PATH=${TORCH_BASE_PATH})

set(Torch_INCLUDE_DIR "${TORCH_BASE_PATH}/include")
set(Torch_LIBRARIES "${TORCH_BASE_PATH}/lib")
# target_link_libraries is to be preferred
#link_directories(${Torch_LIBRARIES})
find_library(LIBRARY_TORCH TH HINTS ${Torch_LIBRARIES})
#[[ 
    even simpler
    if you use the vcpkg toolchain file "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

        find_path(Torch_INCLUDE_DIR TH/TH.h)
        find_library(LIBRARY_TORCH TH)
    ]]

add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${Torch_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test ${LIBRARY_TORCH})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
#set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved it as I mentioned in the comments by adding `/home/afshin/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Also, I think the code that you suggested works for windows, and I am a Linux user.

Comment: Not at all, it is cross-platform. I will test it in a minute, I am in Windows, but it is BootCamp so I will switch to macOS. On the other hand, I do not use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, I prefer `find_path` and `find_library`.

Comment: Yes, I see that it is trying to automatically solve the problems. As windows, since I see `x64-windows` in the roots, I said the provided code is meant to be for Windows. I understood that `vcpkg` is a cross OS tools.

Comment: It builds under macOS, but it is trickier: a new triplet is needed (instead of the default x64-osx).

Comment: three questions: In windows, how can I install Vcpkg? I see that there is a Visual Studio requirement. Can I instead use Eclipse? The link that you sent is for torch-th which is pretty old part of torch. Does it work for libtroch C++?

Comment: 1) `clone`, then `.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` 3) normally, `.\vcpkg install torch-th --head` gets the latest version, even if not already officially integrated. `vcpkg` manages only the listed packets, so if you want something else ... you are on your own. `vcpkg` is interesting when you need more packets.

Comment: 2) `VS Community` is free, but I think you can manage without, but you will still be needing `Platform SDK` at least.  Maybe also `VS Tools`, likewise on `macOS` you still need `Xcode` tools even if you do not use XCode directly. I really do not know, sorry, you have to experiment ... or ask :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used `cmake4ecplise` and I was able to build my code. But, it does not run successfully and terminates with a non-zero return. I posted a question about it in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873603/libtorch-with-cmake-via-eclipse-in-windowsterminated-exit-value-390