# LibTorch with CMake via Eclipse in Windows:Terminated exit value 390

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, torch, libtorch

I used cmake4eclipse to build torch C++ version 1.0 stable in Windows 10. Basically, I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` to build the `mnist` example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(mnist)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/rl/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
set(Torch_DIR "C:/rl/libtorch")

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

option(DOWNLOAD_MNIST "Download the MNIST dataset from the internet" ON)
if (DOWNLOAD_MNIST)
  message(STATUS "Downloading MNIST dataset")
  execute_process(
    COMMAND python ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/download_mnist.py
      -d ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/data
    ERROR_VARIABLE DOWNLOAD_ERROR)
  if (DOWNLOAD_ERROR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Error downloading MNIST dataset: ${DOWNLOAD_ERROR}")
  endif()
endif()

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) 
add_executable(mnist mnist.cpp)
target_compile_features(mnist PUBLIC cxx_range_for)
set_property(TARGET mnist PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
target_link_libraries(mnist ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```

Then, I load this along with the `mnist.cpp` and `download_mnist.py` files in a folder and start a project in `eclipse IDE for C/C++`, version `2018-09 (4.9.0)`. In **project_properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor**, I set `CMake Builder (GNU Make)` and select `MinGW GCC`. Then, in **project_properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths Macros etc.->Providers** I select `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS Parser [Shared]` and move it up, as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453851/how-to-configure-eclipse-cdt-for-cmake/38716337).

Then, I can compile the `mnist` project without any error. But, when I run it get `<terminated> (exit value 390) a.exe [some address]`. I tried to debug this code to find out the problem, but I cannot see the debug screen, and instead I get:

[image]

Running the debug mode to the end results in a same error. 
I can run `mnist.cpp` in Linux without any problem, though I use `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ./` to create a `eclipse` project. I did not know how I can use `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ./` in Windows and I used `cmake4eclipse` and I believe I have missed a step in dealing with the `CMakeLists.txt` file in windows. I appreciate any help or comments.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked same question in torch git, and today I got an answer for that. It seems that for now, we will not be able to run Libtorch through Eclipse with MinGw. Here is the answer that I got from torch git page:

"I don't think you could build that with MinGW because the code is written in c++ and MinGW is not abi-compatible with MSVC. So I think you may need to compile with MSVC. And also in MSVC, the configuration debug and release could not be mixed. So you will have to choose Release as we only provide library with the Release configuration."

See more details in:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15711